# ASP.NET MVC View is showing NULL

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a Controller that I have hard coded some values and expect the values to populate the 2 models with the data.  However, there is one Model that is null when I run through the controller.  Here are some snippets of the app.

When I run the code, Orders is `null`.  I would expect there be 3 entries in customer orders but that is `null`.

`CustomerOrderModel.cs`:

```
public class CustomerOrderModel
{
    public int OrderId { get; set; }
    public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public decimal Total { get; set; }
}
```

`CustomerViewModel.cs`:

```
public class CustomerViewModel
{
    public int CustomerNumber { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FullName
    {
        get { return FirstName + " " + LastName; }
    }
    public List<CustomerOrderModel> Orders { get; set; }
}
```

`Controller.cs`:

```cs
public IActionResult Orders()
{
    decimal iTotal = 55.23M;
    CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel();
    List<CustomerOrderModel> orders = new List<CustomerOrderModel>();

    try
    {
        for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
        {
            var order = new CustomerOrderModel();
            customer.CustomerNumber = 111111;
            customer.FirstName = "John";
            customer.LastName = "Smith";

            order.OrderId = i;
            order.OrderDate = DateTime.Now;
            order.Description = "Part " + i;
            order.Total = iTotal;
            iTotal += order.Total;

            orders.Add(order);
        }
        
        return View(customer);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        return View("Error");
    }
}
```

[image: customer object]

[image: orders object]

I have tried to re-code the `IActionResult Orders()` without any luck. `customer.Orders` gives me no members.

Re-code Orders

```cs
public IActionResult Orders1()
{
    decimal iTotal = 55.23M;
    List<CustomerOrderModel> orders = new List<CustomerOrderModel>();

    for (int i = 1; i < 4; i++)
    {
        CustomerViewModel customer = new CustomerViewModel();
        customer.Orders = new List<CustomerOrderModel>();
        customer.CustomerNumber = 111111;
        customer.FirstName = "John";
        customer.LastName = "Smith";
    }
    return View();
}
```

Comment: ASP.NET MVC (on the full, classic, Windows-only **.NET** framework) - or ASP.NET **Core** MVC ? You've tagged both - please be precise!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include your code as **text** rather than as screenshot(s). On stack overflow images should not be used for textual content, see [*Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557) and [*Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/307500) for why. For instructions on formatting see *[How do I format my code blocks?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/22186)*. A [mcve] showing what you have tried that did not work would maximize your chances of getting help. See [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the `public IActionResult Orders()` action method set the `Orders` property value before render the view:

```cs
customer.Orders = orders; 
return View(customer);
```

The reference type default value is `null` and this what you see.

---

[Default values of C# types (C# reference)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/builtin-types/default-values)